# How do create a text file in a specified location using python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a text file using python. Here is my code-

```
import sys
import os

str1="a1.txt"
file1="Documents/Inbox/"
completeName=file1+str1
name1=os.path.abspath(completeName)
myfile = open(name1, 'w')
```

I want to save file `a1.txt` in my documents folder in my home directory.I get the following error using above code-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filesave.py", line 8, in <module>
    myfile = open(name1, 'w')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/pulkit/Documents/Documents/Inbox/a1.txt'
```

Comment: Does `/home/pulkit/Documents/Documents/Inbox` exist?

Comment: Where do you exactly to create it?

Comment: Do you have a directory named `/home/pulkit/Documents/Documents/Inbox/`?

Comment: @dhke No ` /home/pulkit/Documents/Inbox/` exists

Comment: So the answer is obvious: `file1="Inbox/"`

Comment: Got it I am using absolutepath so I think Documents is already included in the path by default.Yes @Alex.S

Comment: You were probably running the code at the Documents folder already, which caused this error.

Comment: you can use `subprocess` module. `import subprocess; subprocess.call(['touch', 'a1.txt'])`
or os module (not recommended)
`os.system('touch a1.txt')`

Comment: You should not hard-depend on `~/Documents`, anyway. While it looks like the folks at FreeDesktop failed to document the "well known" directories in a real specification ([arch wiki with non-normative documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xdg_user_directories)), but the [accompanying library](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-user-dirs/) makes it clear, that the documents directory is user configurable.

Comment: @marmeladze Using an external tool to make the file exist is wasteful and unnecessary, and clearly not the problem the OP was trying to solve anyway. (Read the question, not just the title.) For what it's worth, opening and immediately closing the file in Python would accomplish the same thing without an external process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.path.abspath()` does not know which directory you *want* the file to exist in -- it simply uses the current directory, which seems to have been `$HOME/Documents` when you got the backtrace.

Either

1. always run the script from your home directory (untenable); or
2. specify an explicit absolute path in the script; or
3. change the logic so the script doesn't care where it's run -- commonly this is done by creating a file in the current directory always; or by simply printing to standard output, and let the user figure out what to do with the output.

Comment: Thank you. What is the alternative to abspath. It seems to work in this case but if I have to save it in some other folder not in current path it will fail

Comment: How can I specify an explicit absolute path?

Comment: `name1 = "/home/pulkit/Documents/Inbox/a1.txt"`.  But this is definitely the least attractive option, to my mind.

Answer (score 3):

This code shows you how to check the path exists and expand `~` to access home directory of the user running the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
dpath=os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"),"Documents","Inbox")
if not os.path.exists(dpath):
    os.makedirs(dpath)
fpath=os.path.join(dpath,"a1.txt")
open(fpath,"w").write("what ever you want")
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case omit the 'Documents/' from your variable file1 setting like:

`file1="Inbox/"`

Answer (score 0):

See the error

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/pulkit/Documents/Documents/Inbox/a1.txt'

Clearly, the path evaluated is:

```
/home/pulkit/Documents/Documents/Inbox/a1.txt
```

But you have,

```
/home/pulkit/Documents/Inbox/a1.txt
```

So, change `file1="Documents/Inbox/"` to `file1="Inbox/"`